# How to remove array elements contained in another array

Tags: php, arrays, splice

I have an array like

```
<?php
 $array1 = array(1,2,3,5);
 $array2 = array(1,3,4,5,6,7);

?>
```

i want `$array3` to look like

```
 $array3 = array(4,6,7);
```

In simple words remove elements of `$array2` if contained in `$array1`
i am a newbie searched a lot but didnt found anything.Help would be thanked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
$result = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Note that the order of arguments is important here. The above statement checks `$array2` against `$array1` and  returns the values in `$array2` that are *not* present in `$array1`.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 4
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
)
```

Comment: Now if i want the array to be like `Array([1]=>4,[2]=>6,[3]=7)` then what 2 do?

Comment: @user3560703: `$result = array_values(array_diff($array2, $array1));` (But that'll give `Array([0]=>4,[1]=>6,[2]=7)`, which I assume, is what you want). [See demo](https://eval.in/139598).